# docker-storage-setup command is missing

Tags: docker, redhat

I don't know what happend, the command `docker-storage-setup` was working form me couple of weeks ago and now it doesn't.
After I run it, I received:

```
[root@master ~]# docker-storage-setup
-bash: docker-storage-setup: command not found
```

I tried to install but it also failed:

```
[root@master ~]# yum install -y docker-storage-setup
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
No package docker-storage-setup available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I have RedHat 7.6 machine:

```
[root@master ~]# hostnamectl
   Static hostname: master
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: 00000000000000000000000000000000
           Boot ID: 00000000000000000000000000000000
    Virtualization: vmware
  Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.6:GA:server
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-957.21.2.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

How can I reinstall it ?

**EDIT:**
@mchawre, the service cannot be found:

```
[root@master ~]# systemctl status docker-storage-group
Unit docker-storage-group.service could not be found.
```

@mchawre when I ran `yum whatprovides docker-storage-setup` I got:

```
[root@master ~]# yum whatprovides docker-storage-setup
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
rhel-7-server-ansible-2.6-rpms/x86_64/filelists_db                                                                                                                                                                    | 332 kB  00:00:00
rhel-7-server-rpms/7Server/x86_64/filelists_db                                                                                                                                                                        |  40 MB  00:00:00
No matches found
```

Comment: can you check `systemctl status docker-storage-group`, try `yum whatprovides docker-storage-setup`

Comment: I guess this `docker-storage-setup` automatically gets installed with `docker`. Also as a last option try to install `container-storage-setup`.

Comment: @mchawre I updated my answer with your questions.

Comment: Try `yum-config-manager --enable rhel-7-server-extras-rpms` and then try to install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install `container-storage-setup` which was formerly known as `docker-storage-setup`

Check [this](https://github.com/projectatomic/container-storage-setup#container-storage-setup) out.

Quoting the line here from above mentioned link.

> container-storage-setup is part of the Project Atomic suite of
>   container projects, formerly known as docker-storage-setup.

Also check [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/managing_containers/managing_storage_with_docker_formatted_containers) official rehdat documentation.

Quoting the NOTE mentioned in above link here.

> Prior to RHEL 7.4, the container-storage-setup utility was called
>   docker-storage-setup. As with previous RHEL Server and RHEL Atomic
>   releases, you can add storage settings to
>   /etc/sysconfig/docker-storage-setup as input, which results in those
>   settings being placed in /etc/sysconfig/docker-storage as output.

Since you are using RedHat 7.6, `conatiner-storage-setup` is the correct package.

`yum install -y container-storage-setup` should work.

Hope this helps, let me know.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't need to install it, it was already installed. Weird, maybe I did some update and it changed the `docker-storage-setup` to `container-storage-setup`.